# PDO view insert details of query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am inserting some data in to a table, and I need to get the id of that query to insert in to another query straight after that query.

```
$database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
$addproduct = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO products(title, description, price,
    startingprice, buyitnow, itemcondition, shortdescription, enddate, offers, 
    location, shipping, quantity, date, username) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$result = $addproduct->execute(array($title, $maindescription, $price, $startingprice,
    $type, $condition, $shortdescription, $enddate, $offers, $country,
    $shipping, $quantity, date("Y-m-d: H:i:s"), $user->username));

print_r($result);

if($result):
    //add bid for min price to stop fetching every second
    $addbid = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO bids(bids_amount,bids_timestamp, bids_username, bids_item) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
    $addbid->execute(array($price, strtotime("NOW"), $user->username, $result->id));
    return 2;
else:
    return 3;
endif;
```

As you can see i am trying to get the id of the last query and insert that into my second query in to 'bids_items'.

How can I get an array of the data I insert in my first query?

Comment: This should help: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php. `$database->lastInsertId();` should get you the ID of the last insert query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use LastInsertId:

```
$result = $addproduct->execute(...);
$inserted_id = $database->lastInsertId;
```

Then use $inserted_id as needed in upcoming queries